# Goutte crawl returns empty node

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, web-crawler, goutte

I am using Goutte to crawl a set of URLS that contain href and price to extract data for my application. It works great, but some URLs give me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The current node list is empty.'
```

And the following returns zero even if the element exist on the page:

```
$crawler->filter('.bp-2-show h3 a')->count()
```

Here is the code:

```
$crawler->filter("#serp-list-new ul li")->each(function (Crawler $node, $i){
                $u = $node->filter('.bp-2-show h3 a')->attr('href');
                $p = $node->filter('.bp-2-show .money')->text();                                                           
            });
```

I cannot make this work. It happens to some URLs.

Using Laravel 5.3
Package: dweidner/laravel-goutte